# Java Math RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN prints unexpected result

Tags: java, math, rounding

i was trying to debug an issue with rounding for HALF_EVEN i java, 
as you could see below, the unexpected result is 377.35, we could have expected it prints 377.34?

Can someone help to explain the behavior?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.out.println((new BigDecimal(0.3450)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString());
    //prints 0.34

    System.out.println((new BigDecimal(77.3450)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString());
    //prints 77.34

    System.out.println((new BigDecimal(377.3450)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString());
    **//prints 377.35 ?????**

    //anything larger than 256 is printing .35 
    System.out.println((new BigDecimal(255.3450)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString());
    //prints 255.34 

    System.out.println((new BigDecimal(256.3450)).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN).toPlainString());
    **//prints 256.35 ?????** 


}
```

Comment: @JonnyHenly i believe that is the same question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new BigDecimal(377.3450)
```

This line, alone, loses all the advantages of `BigDecimal`, because you're passing in a `double` in the first place, and that does all the rounding you don't want.

Write, instead,

```
new BigDecimal("377.3450")
```

...and generally use the `String` constructors everywhere.  In the cases where you got the "right" answer, the floating point rounding got *lucky* and went in the right direction.